# A question on limit of ratio of exponentials?

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

I am quite rusty on calculus, when I plot this $f(x) = \frac{2^{x^2}}{L^{x(x-1)/6}}$ on [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ch3u47uoyd), It seems to me both intuitively and from the plot that the $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty f(x)}$ will shift between $0$ and $\infty$ depending on $L$. For example check $L=20$ and $L=100$.

I would like to evaluate $L$ for which this transition would happen, I tried with L'Hopital, but I don't think it would work as th exponentials will remain after differentiating too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking the logarithm of your function we get

$\log(2)x^2-\frac{\log(L)}{6}(x^2+x)$

From this we see (the log) of $f$ goes to -infinity if $\log(2)<\frac{\log(L)}{6}$, or in other words, if $L>e^{6\log(2)}=64$. Therefore, $f$ goes to $0$ when $L\ge 64$, and infinity otherwise.

Comment: It is $x^2-x$ instead of $x^2+x$, that's why our answers disagree for $L=64$. Your answer is similar but shorter than mine, +1!

Comment: I see, and +1 to your answer aswell :). Reason I wrote x^2 + x is that that is what's writte in OP's desmos.

Answer (score 2):

Let $M=L^{1/6}$ and $N=\frac{2}{M}$. Then

$$f(x) = \frac{2^{x^2}}{M^{x^2-x}}  = \frac{2^{x^2}}{M^{x^2}M^{-x}} 
=
\left(\frac{2}{M}\right)^{x^2} M^x
=
N^{x^2}M^x 
=
e^{x^2\ln(N)+x\ln(M)}$$

Therefore, we only need to consider the limit of the function $g(x)=x^2\ln(N)+x\ln(M)$:

1. $\ln(N)>0$ (equivalent to $N>1 \iff 2>M \iff L<2^6=64$), then $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\infty$, and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$.
2. if $\ln(N)<0$ (equivalent to $L>2^6=64$), then $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=-\infty$, and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$
3. if $\ln(N)=0$ (equivalent to $L=64$), then $M=2$ so $\ln(M)>0$. It follows that $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\infty$, and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$.